# The sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ are divergent, but their difference is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I got a bit confused when trying to find the convergence status and limit of the following sequence:

$$f(n) = \frac{n^2}{n+1} - \frac{n^2+1}{n}$$

My conjecture was that the limit of this sequence does NOT exist. To make the working somewhat simpler, I tried to separately find the limit of

$$g(n) = \frac{n^2}{n+1}$$

and

$$h(n) =  \frac{n^2+1}{n}$$

Using the Reciprocal Rule, I found $g, h$ go to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity. From what I learned is that if two sequences to to infinity, then their sum also goes to infinity.

I concluded that $f(n)$ therefore goes to infinity. However [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20n%5E2%2F%28n%2B1%29%20-%20%28n%5E2%2B1%29%2Fn%20as%20n%20goes%20to%20infinity) tells me that the limit of $f(n)$ is $-1$.

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you simplify $f(n)$ into a single rational function? If so, what is the limit of the rational function?

Comment: It's now the *difference* of $g$ and $h$, not the sum. Anyway, have you tried a common denominator?

Comment: So the mistake is that I didn't first simplify $f(n)= 1/(n + 1) - 1/n - 1$ before looking at the individual fractions.

Comment: Not so much as "mistake", but maybe just not familiar with finding limits. The limit of a single rational function is very well understood (by comparing degrees and then leading coefficients). So, if you are able to combine it into 1 term, then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial to find examples such that the sequences diverge whence the difference converges, such as $g(n)=n,h(n)=n$.
Wolfram alpha is quite right since $f(n)=\frac{n^3-(n^2+1)(n+1)}{n(n+1)}$, where the upper part is just $n^3-(n^3+n^2+n+1)=-n^2-n-1$ hence $f(n)=-1-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, where the latter part of the sum tends to 0 as $n$ tends to infinity.